# Can't increment product's quantity in session object

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I created an object, it's named carwash. I created a session and assigned that object for session, if I enter quantity then and press buy button, I have result (example 6):

> > Your shopping cart contains 6 items.

but when I enter nothing, I get:

> > Your shopping cart contains items.

How should I do? Thank you! Here is all my code:

index.php 
PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();  

    require_once 'carwash.php'; 
    if (isset($_SESSION['encoded_cartopass'])) { 
        // first let's get the variable from the session 
        $encoded_cartopass = $_SESSION['encoded_cartopass']; 

        // now let's unpack it 
        $cartopass = unserialize($encoded_cartopass); 

        // echo quantity 
        echo "Your shopping cart contains {$cartopass->getQuantity()} items. <br /><br />"; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo "Your shopping cart contains 0 items. <br /><br />"; 
    } 
?> 



    <form action="process.php" method="post"> 
    Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Buy" name="submit" /> 
    </form>
```

process.php 
PHP Code:

```
<?php 

    require_once 'carwash.php'; 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

        if (!isset($_SESSION['encoded_cartopass'])) { 

            // construct and set quantity 
            $cartopass = new carwash(); 
            $cartopass->setQuantity($_POST['quantity']); 

            // construct and encode session 
            session_register('encoded_cartopass'); 
            $_SESSION['encoded_cartopass'] = serialize($cartopass); 
        } 
        else { 
            // if session is existing, decode it and 
            // increment quantity 
            $encoded_cartopass = $_SESSION['encoded_cartopass']; 

            $cartopass = unserialize($encoded_cartopass); 

            $cartopass->incrementQuantity($_POST['quantity']); 

            // encode class and assign to session and 
            // session is used pass to index.php 
            $_SESSION['encode_cartopass'] = serialize($cartopass); 
        } 

    } 

    echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>"; 
?>
```

carwash.php 
PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    class carwash { 

        private $carmake; 
        private $caryear; 
        private $quantity; 

        public function getCarmake() { 
            return $this->carmake; 
        } 

        public function setCarmake($carmake) { 
            $this->carmake = $carmake; 
        } 

        public function getCaryear() { 
            return $this->caryear; 
        } 

        public function setCaryear($caryear) { 
            $this->caryear = $caryear; 
        } 

        public function getQuantity() { 
            return $this->quantity; 
        } 

        public function setQuantity($quantity) { 
            $this->quantity = $quantity; 
        } 

        public function incrementQuantity($quantity = '') { 
            if (empty($quantity)) { 
                $this->quantity++; 
            } 
            else { 
                $this->quantity += $quantity; 
            } 
        } 

        public function washcar() { 
            echo "scruba, dub, dub, scruba, dub, dub <br />"; 
            echo "I'm feelling cleaner, Thank you!"; 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Can you do public function setQuantity($quantity = 0) { ?

Comment: Ha, I didn't think that would work, so I posted some alternative "display hacks". But glad you got it.

Comment: Sure, it didn't work. May be I have some logic problems, but I tried other approach and it worked. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: (Found out what the curly braces do...)
Either of the following should work:

```
echo "Your shopping cart contains ".($cartopass->getQuantity() ? $cartopass->getQuantity() : 0)." items. <br /><br />"; 

echo "Your shopping cart contains ", $cartopass->getQuantity() + 0, " items. <br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions -

1. Check if the value of session was `"0"` (even though "0" is false, `$v = "0"; isset($v)` will return true).
2. destroy the session if `$_POST` was `"0"`.

### change your index.php to -

```
<?php 
session_start();  

require_once 'carwash.php'; 
if (isset($_SESSION['encoded_cartopass']) && $_SESSION['encoded_cartopass']) { 
    // first let's get the variable from the session 
    $encoded_cartopass = $_SESSION['encoded_cartopass']; 

    // now let's unpack it 
    $cartopass = unserialize($encoded_cartopass); 

    // echo quantity 
    echo "Your shopping cart contains {$cartopass->getQuantity()} items. <br /><br />"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "Your shopping cart contains 0 items. <br /><br />"; 
} 
?>
```

### or change your process.php to -

```
<?php 

require_once 'carwash.php'; 

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['quantity']) { 

    if (!isset($_SESSION['encoded_cartopass'])) { 

        // construct and set quantity 
        $cartopass = new carwash(); 
        $cartopass->setQuantity($_POST['quantity']); 

        // construct and encode session 
        session_register('encoded_cartopass'); 
        $_SESSION['encoded_cartopass'] = serialize($cartopass); 
    } 
    else { 
        // if session is existing, decode it and 
        // increment quantity 
        $encoded_cartopass = $_SESSION['encoded_cartopass']; 

        $cartopass = unserialize($encoded_cartopass); 

        $cartopass->incrementQuantity($_POST['quantity']); 

        // encode class and assign to session and 
        // session is used pass to index.php 
        $_SESSION['encode_cartopass'] = serialize($cartopass); 
    } 

} else {
    unset($_SESSION['cartopass']);
    session_destroy();
}

echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>"; 
?>
```